# Move n responsive Navbar from top to bottom when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How could I move a responsive Navbar from top to bottom when resizing? would you use CSS media or Jquery?

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  } #navbar{position: bottom: 0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: sticky;
    right: 0;
    bottom:0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;

  }

}
```

Comment: You need to read this [ask] and this [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited:**

Okay, I assume you don't use any libraries (for example Bootstrap) and would like to show only a single navbar without any dropdown list. In this case, this CSS would do the trick!

And next time also provide some HTML code please. :)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .sticky {
    top: 0!important;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .sticky {
    bottom: 0;
  }
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="navbar" class="sticky">
    <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">News</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h3>Sticky Navigation Example</h3>
    <p>The navbar will stick to the top or bottom, depending on the screen size. Open it in full view.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint
      efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks, and how would you insert it, I added the code above, sorry I am a beginner with this:-)

Comment: Thanks a million:-) This was what I was looking for :-)